# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset 3 in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Am testing with an realtime application upto 40 users everything going fine after 40 users if i increased users to 45 or 50 and so on getting `java.net.socketexception`:`connection reset` errors could you please suggest a solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it indicates an issue with your application, check if there are any suspicious entries which can shed light on the root cause in your application logs. It might also be a configuration issue of any middleware (load balancers, routers, switches, proxies, etc.)

---

If you absolutely sure that your application behaves as expected you can tune JMeter to do retries on connection resets (however this will make your test not realistic from browser perspective), in order to do this:

1. In *user.properties* file add the next lines:

   ```
   httpclient4.retrycount=1
   hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
   ```
2. In *hc.parameters* add the next line:

   ```
   http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
   ```
3. Restart JMeter to pick up the changes.

References:

- [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)